# Trouble Arranging SceneKit Nodes into a Grid

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to arrange a collection of nodes into a grid, I have three different sized nodes so I'm arranging them from biggest to smallest in a square-ish grid.

If all the nodes are the same size, it works great I have a neat grid of nodes, all tightly packed together

```
[][][]
[][][]
[][][]
```

the problem comes when a new row contains a node that's smaller than the previous node then I get an extra space between rows

```
[][][]
[][][]

[][][]
```

I do want a space in between rows (and columns) however I want to be able to control the size of that space.

I'm going out of my mind. I can't see anything in my code that would add this extra space. I know the issue is because of the different sized node but I don't know how it's happening.

I don't think it's an issue with the

I'm currently running this in a playground.

```
public static func grid(theseObjects: [SCNNode]) -> SCNNode {
        let nodesSortedByVolume = theseObjects.sorted(by: {$0.volume > $1.volume } )

    let finalNode = SCNNode()
    var xOffset: Float = 0.0
    var zOffset: Float = 0.0
    let gridSize = Int(Double(theseObjects.count).squareRoot().rounded())


    for (index, node) in nodesSortedByVolume.enumerated() {
        let adjustedIndex = index + 1

        node.position = SCNVector3(xOffset, 0.0, zOffset)
        finalNode.addChildNode(node)
        xOffset += node.width //(node.width + self.spacer)

        if (adjustedIndex >= gridSize) && adjustedIndex.isMultiple(of: gridSize)  {

            zOffset += node.depth
            xOffset = 0.0
        }
    }

    return finalNode
}
```

Edit: I've added default box nodes, to remove any doubt that it's an issue with my models and it makes it simpler to look at the math of the positioning. I've added print statements to show where the nodes are being placed:

```
Placing node.name: "large box 1" at node.position.z:0.0, node.position.x:0.0 zOffset: 0.0
    node.depth is 2.0
    node.name "large box 1" is at finalNode.position.z: 0.0, finalNode.position.x: 0.0

    Placing node.name: "large box 2" at node.position.z:0.0, node.position.x:2.0 zOffset: 0.0
    node.depth is 2.0
    node.name "large box 2" is at finalNode.position.z: 0.0, finalNode.position.x: 2.0

setup new row with zOffset of 2.0

    Placing node.name: "small box 1" at node.position.z:2.0, node.position.x:0.0 zOffset: 2.0
    node.depth is 1.0
    node.name "small box 1" is at finalNode.position.z: 2.0, finalNode.position.x: 0.0

    Placing node.name: "small box 2" at node.position.z:2.0, node.position.x:1.0 zOffset: 2.0
    node.depth is 1.0
    node.name "small box 2" is at finalNode.position.z: 2.0, finalNode.position.x: 1.0
```

As you can see, the small boxes are being placed at a z position of 2.0 which should result in no gap, however when you look at the screenshot below there is a significant gap.

[image: Image of the output with a gap]

If I add more large boxes, they grid correctly until a new size is introduced:

[image: Boxes of the same type grid correctly, until a new size is introduced]

Comment: Hello, What is node.depth and node.width ? Extension ? Why don't you use boundingBox of node geometry ?

Comment: Yes, it’s an extension that gets the height, width and depth of the node from the boundingBox.

Comment: Have you print boundingBox values ? Do you have correct values ? Do you change pivot ?

Comment: Values are correct. I now this because if I only use, say the “small” node they all grid nicely same goes if I only use the “medium” or “large” nodes. It’s only when I mix them that it goes strange. I’ve tried editing the pivot on the individual nodes and it doesn’t affect the positioning at all.

Comment: Can you send more code ?

Comment: I don't have any more code. That's my whole class. The only other code I have loads the objects from SCN files, copies the required amount of objects (e.g. 3 Large, 1 Medium and 1 Small) and places them in the array that is passed to this method. I've edited my question with printed values and I can't see where a space is being added.

Comment: If you're positioning from the centre of the node, you don't want to add the node depth, you want to add half of the previous node and half of the new node. Your small nodes position should be 1.5.

Comment: Or changing the pivot of the nodes should also work.
`node.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, -0.5 * node.depth);`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for printed values.
When you create your SCNNode, the geometry is centered around pivot point. So if you have a geometry cube  with dimension : 200 x 200 x 200 units, the boundingbox goes from (-100, -100, -100) to (100, 100, 100).

In your loop, you add 200 units when you want to change line.
Infact you must add half (100 units) and and half of next SNNode (50 units).

Here is two images to explain :

Result with your actual code

[image: Result with your actual code]

You add 200 units but you must only add half height of first line grid (100 units) and half height of second line grid (50 units).

[image]

Hope this help ! 
Like mentionned by @James P, it's more easily to change pivot point...

Sorry for my awful english.

Comment: This makes complete sense now, I can totally see where I was going wrong. Great explanation. Thank you 